# why do i need to just '()'" at the end of JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I'm trying to understand the difference between :

```
var x = function () {  ....}

(function () { ....} ) ();
```

I get it that the first function will put the results on `x`.

that and when exactly the second one will be fired? and why do i need the `();` at the end?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167554/function-returning-a-function-to-a-variable-why-does-it-need-the-extra-set-of ?

Comment: The first one doesn't put the results in `x`, it sets `x` to the function.

Comment: `(function() {...})();` is the same as `function foo() {....}; (foo)();`.

Comment: @FelixKling:thats almost the same..if u leave out scoping features that IIFE involves

Comment: @Onaseriousnote: `foo` will have the same scope behaviour as the anonymous function. Or do you mean that the anonymous function is not accessible anywhere else? That's of course a difference.

Comment: why is it so important to use iife..i have seen people using this when the job can be done using simple function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the [Immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression#Usage).

The function is executed immediately because `()` is how JavaScript calls functions. The syntax might be confuse you, because the function does not have a name, but `(   function(){}  )()` just immediately calls the function with no arguments.